# Change UI culture programmatically in WinCE 5 / .NET CF 2

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

In a standard .NET framework application (not CF), I can change the user UI culture with:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-AR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

but the .NET CF 2 doesn't support CurrentUICulture for CurrentThread.

So far, I found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140329222308/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bitsnpieces/archive/2009/07/15/switching-cultures-at-runtime-on-windows-ce.aspx) that maybe the UI culture can be changed by setting

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\nls\overrides]\LCID
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\MUI]\CurLang
```

but it requires rebooting the device after the change.
Is there any other way to do it?

TIA,
Pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Instead of hacking the registry, use the documented SetUserDefaultUILanguage() API function.  From the remarks section of that API:

*The new LANGID will not take effect until the device is reset.*

Can't get around that.  Shouldn't be a problem, users don't change their native language frequently.

Comment: Mm, from the Visual Studio 2008 .NET CF Help:

"You cannot set current culture programmatically on a device. They are set by the device manufacturer..."

and no help on SetUserDefaultUILanguage, it appears to be supported in .NET CF 4.2 (I'm using .NET CF 2)